# Canon MG5320 not recognized by Simple Scan (prints fine)

Tags: canon, scanner

Displays 'No scanners detected' 'Please check if connected and power on'

Answer (score 2):

Located deb files from Canon Asia, installed via software center and `scangearmp` runs from terminal.

Comment: You can also download their ScanGear MP utility from the same link, and then scan from within GIMP. File/Create/ScanGear MP... It's not as good as HP's printer support but it does work.

Comment: the command is `scangearmp`, not `scanmp`.

Answer (score 0):

Download the software on the canon site: MP Navigator EX Ver. 5.0.2
Search your printer on their website, select the correct printer, select or let them auto detect your windows version and find the MP Navigator EX Ver. 5.0.2 software.

Success!!!

Answer (score -1):

You can also use XSANE, available in Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please avoid posting [the same answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/340087) in more than one place. When tempted to do so, typically: (1) the answer should be customized to account for differences between the different questions, (2) one question should be flagged for closure as a duplicate of another (you can flag posts with [15 reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts)), (3) the answer should really be a comment, **or** (4) the answer should be posted in the most appropriate place, and one-line comments posted on other questions summarizing and linking to it.

Comment: Anyway, installing xsane doesn't help...