# Help with scanning Issue

Tags: scanning

How do I set up the Lexmark S505 printer so it will scan documents?  It prints fine, but I can't get it to scan documents into my computer.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you using? What are you using as scan application?

Answer (score 0):

You can try xsane, available in ubuntu software centre.

Comment: @Deepak This seems like an answer, but can you tell us more about xsane, how to use it, and possibly why you think it will work better than `simple-scan` or whatever else the author of this question is currently using?